# Calling insertion sort class from driver doesn't work

Tags: java, sorting

The bubble sort sorting in the driver class works fine but I make a new list and try to do insertion sort and it just doesn't sort the list. I was thinking it was something with the setSortBehavior method in the first Listing class but everything I've tried hasn't worked.
package strategydesignpattern;
import java.util.ArrayList;

```
public class Listing {
    protected String title;
    protected ArrayList<String> items;
    protected SortBehavior theSortBehavior;

/**
 * Creates a list with the indicated name
 * @param title The title of the list
 */
    public Listing(String title)
    {
        this.title = title;
        this.items = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.theSortBehavior = new BubbleSort();
    }
/**
 * Adds an item to the list
 * @param item the item you want to add to the list
 */
    public void add(String item)
    {
        items.add(item);
    }
/**
 * removes an item from the list
 * @param item the item you want to remove from the list
 */
    public void remove(String item)
    {
        items.remove(item);
    }
/**
 * a getter for the name of the list
 * @return returns the title of the list
 */
    public String getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }
/**
 * sets the sort behavior to whatever is passed in
 * @param sortBehavior gets the sort behavior, either insertion or bubble
 */
    public void setSortBehavior(SortBehavior sortBehavior)
    {
        theSortBehavior = sortBehavior;
    }
/**
 * 
 * @return returns the sorted list of items
 */
    public ArrayList<String> getSortedList()
    {
        return theSortBehavior.sort(items);
    }
/**
 * 
 * @return returns the unsorted list of items
 */
    public ArrayList<String> getUnSortedList()
    {
        return items;
    }
}
```

//////

```
package strategydesignpattern;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public interface SortBehavior  {
    public ArrayList<String> sort(ArrayList<String> data);
    
}
```

///

```
package strategydesignpattern;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BubbleSort implements SortBehavior{
    public ArrayList<String> sort(ArrayList<String> data)
    {
        String temp;
        boolean sorted = false;
    
        while (!sorted) {
            sorted = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < data.size()-1; i++) {
                if (data.get(i).compareTo(data.get(i + 1)) > 0) {
                    temp = data.get(i);
                    data.set(i, data.get(i + 1));
                    data.set(i + 1, temp);
                    sorted = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

//

```
package strategydesignpattern;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class InsertionSort implements SortBehavior{
    public ArrayList<String> sort(ArrayList<String> data)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < data.size(); j++) {
            String current = data.get(j);
            int i = j-1;
            while ((i > -1) && ((data.get(i).compareTo(current)) == 1)) {
                data.set(i+1, data.get(i));
                i--;
            }
            data.set(i+1, current);
        }

        return data;

    }

}
```

////

```
package strategydesignpattern;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Creates lists of information, and displays the sorted versions of the lists
 */
public class ListDriver {

    /**
     * Creates a new ListDriver
     */
    public ListDriver(){}

    /**
     * Main entryway to the program
     * Creates the lists, and displays the sorted lists
     */
    public void run() {
        Listing shoppingList = new Listing("Grocery List");
        shoppingList.add("Apples");
        shoppingList.add("Peaches");
        shoppingList.add("Cheese");
        shoppingList.add("Crackers");
        shoppingList.add("Chocolate");
        shoppingList.add("Cherries");
        shoppingList.add("Bananas");
        shoppingList.add("Oranges");

        ArrayList<String> sortedGroceryItems = shoppingList.getSortedList();
        System.out.println(shoppingList.getTitle());
        displayList(sortedGroceryItems);

        Listing wishList = new Listing("Wish List");
        wishList.setSortBehavior(new InsertionSort());
        wishList.add("Bike");
        wishList.add("Paddle Board");
        wishList.add("Boat");
        wishList.add("Truck");
        wishList.add("Puzzle");
        wishList.add("Monolopy");
        wishList.add("Skipping Rope");
        wishList.add("Cherry Tree");

        ArrayList<String> sortedWishListItems = wishList.getSortedList();
        System.out.println("\n" + wishList.getTitle());
        displayList(sortedWishListItems);
    }

    /**
     * Loops through and displays each item in the list items
     * @param items list to display
     */
    private void displayList(ArrayList<String> items){
        for(String item : items){
            System.out.println("- " + item);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ListDriver driver = new ListDriver();
        driver.run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have assumed the `String.compareTo` will return `1` to indicate a lexicographical ordering where the string the method is being invoked on follows the argument string. [The Documenation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)) states that the return value for `String.compareTo` is a positive integer to indicate this lexicographical ordering, not specifically `1`.

Answer (score 0):

I have try to debug your code. I find that *(data.get(i).compareTo(current)) == 1)* is not correct. According to the Java String API (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String))

> The result is a negative integer if this String object lexicographically precedes the argument string. The result is a positive integer if this String object lexicographically follows the argument string. The result is zero if the strings are equal; compareTo returns 0 exactly when the equals(Object) method would return true.

It says the result is a positive integer.